# Definitive advice on BibTeX entries for online material

Tags: bibtex

I'm new (i.e. today!) to LaTex, and am assembling resources for a .bib file using the [BibTex online editor](http://truben.no/latex/bibtex/) (with the help of my more LaTex-savvy partner).

There's no entry category for online articles and resources, so after some research the advice seems to be either use a `url` field in `@MISC`, `@ARTICLE` or `@ELECTRONIC`. I also found [two articles](http://nschloe.blogspot.co.uk/2009/06/bibtex-how-to-cite-website_21.html) that suggest [using `@ONLINE`](http://disasterjs.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/citing-websites-on-bibtex.html), but this seems like an outlier and I'm not sure if it's widely supported?

I've already noticed that the LaTex community can offer varying solutions to a single problem, so I need to know the simplest and—if it exists—the **canonical way to cite online sources**, with a field for 'last accessed'.

### Update

Here's my @ONLINE template (formatting borrowed from the online editor mentioned above):

```
@ONLINE {refkey,
    author    = "",
    title     = "",
    publisher = "",
    month     = "",
    year      = "",
    url       = "http://",
    urldate   = "YYYY-MM-DD"
}
```

Comment: package `biblatex` knows `@online`. It is superior to all the bibtex enhancements and citation packages introduced in the last 20 years.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a guide to which fields to use for `@online` (e.g. `urldate` for last accessed), or can these be any of the available BibTeX fields?

Comment: The documentation of the package (`texdoc biblatex`) lists them all. Also available: http://texdoc.net/ and search for biblatex

Comment: If you want to post these comments as an answer, I'll mark it 'accepted', as I now have the solution I needed.

Comment: Biblatex documentation, p.10. You also can automate using `JabRef` a bibliography manager written  in Java. If you enable the `biblatex` mode, it will present you automatically all the mandatory and optional fields. Btw, you should compile your bibliography with `biber`, which has among other advantages that of understanding utf8.

Comment: I updated my question with the fields I'm using - any obvious mistakes?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Over the years, many packages have been written to do some
special bibliography stuff. Urls  and DOIs became prominent over
the years, and some bibliographystyles have added features to
actually cite online material.

With `biblatex` we have a modern package that tries to implement
all the functunality of the various packages in just one LaTeX
package. It provides a dedicated entrytype for online resources.

Citing the package documentation, version 3.0:

> **online** An online resource. `author`, `editor` and `year` are
>   omissible in terms of § *Missing and Omissible Data*
>   This entrytype is intended for sources such as web sites which
>   are intrisically online resources. Note that all entry types
>   support the `url` field. For example, when adding an article from
>   an online journal, it may be preferable to use the `@article`
>   type and its `url` field.
>
> Required fields: `author/editor`, `title`, `year/date`, `url`
>
> Optional fields, `subtitle`, `titleaddon`, `language`, `version`,
>   `note`, `organization`, `date`, `month`, `year`, `addendum`,
>   `pubstate`, `urldate`

If you have the freedom to choose `biblatex` over any other citation package, feel lucky. On the other hand, contributing to a journal can be a problem. Why update a workflow that is working?

Most journals still use BibTeX with classical bibliography styles. As `biblatex` was adding new features, not everything in a database will be reusable. Thinking about this at the beginning will save you some trouble later.

Comment: Since it looks like the OP has marked this as the canonical answer, it may be a good idea to add a bit more information regarding the first paragraph. Not everyone is free to use `biblatex`, after all...

Comment: @Mico Please undelete your answer, i was hoping for an alternative answer using natbib/apacite. I'll add a paragraph where `biblatex` isn't the way to go, i .e. journal publications.

Answer (score 7):

You haven't indicated which bibliography style you intend to use. Is that because you haven't decided yet which style, or styles, you'll employ?

BibTeX has been around for well more than two decades. The original BibTeX style files -- `plain`, `unsrt`, `abbrv`, `alpha`, `apalike`, and a couple more -- all date back to an era when online resources didn't exist and thus weren't going to be cited. Unsurprisingly, these style files don't accommodate online material all that well. If, for some reason, you must use one of the original BibTeX style files, you're going to have to follow the path you've already identified, *viz.*, use the `note` field of various entry types to store the relevant URL strings.

If you can use the [natbib](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/) citation management package, you should use that package's associated style files -- `plainnat`, `unsrtnat`, and `abbrvnat` -- instead of `plain`, `unsrt`, and `abbrv`. Being of a much more recent vintage, the `natbib` style files do know what to do with fields named `url`, `eid`, and `issn`.

Still working with BibTeX, the [apacite](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/apacite/) citation management package and its associated bib style file (also called `apacite`) offer even more entry types and fields types for each entry, many of them related to online and other electronic features. Do check out table 3 of the package's user guide for detailed information on which fields are recognized by which entries. E.g., you'll find that `doi`, `lastchecked`, `url` and `urldate` fields are recognized by all of the package's entry types (with the exception of the `literal` type, with which I'm not familiar).

For the ultimate (at least for now) in terms of power and flexibility when it comes to bibliography creation and management, do consider switching to the [biblatex](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/) package and the associated external program, called `biber`. It's still in development as of 2015, so things may at times not be as utterly stable as they are in the BibTeX world. (One of the downsides of BibTeX, some would say, is its utter stability -- and immobility.) Unfortunately, because `biblatex` and `biber` are still relatively new, many journals and publishing houses that accept LaTeX documents as inputs will *not* run `biblatex`/`biber`. Thus, it may be a good idea to incorporate at least some backward compatibility in your bib files, so that you can generate, if need be, bibliographies using either BibTeX or `biblatex`/`biber`.

Comment: Thanks. http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23766435#23766435 and the next from me. Feel free to make as many improvements as possible. :-)

Comment: oh, good luck with that :-) See you in chat some time.

Comment: @Mico - I haven't chosen a bibliography style, and the answer from Johannes_B settled the issue that was holding me up in a very direct and understandable manner (I just started with LaTeX today). But that's useful info - I'll look up the references and hopefully emerge with a durable solution.